# Wrong result of (or where query)

Tags: mysql, sql

My query look like:

```
select *
from `games`
    inner join `prowizja` on `prowizja`.`id_gry` = `games`.`id`
where `games`.`status` = 2 and `games`.`winner_user_id` != 49
 and `games`.`owner_user_id` = 49 or `games`.`join_user_id` = 49
```

Important think is **games`.`winner_user_id` != 49**. But I result of this query up is:

[image]

Someone could tell me, why I receive result with winner_user_id 49, but I want not equals.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to wrap the last two predicates of the `WHERE` clause in parentheses:

```
select * 
from `games` 
inner join `prowizja` 
on `prowizja`.`id_gry` = `games`.`id`
where `games`.`status` = 2 and 
      `games`.`winner_user_id` != 49 and
      (`games`.`owner_user_id` = 49 or `games`.`join_user_id` = 49)
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND`has precedence over `OR`. Hence your query equals:

```
select *
from games
inner join prowizja on prowizja.id_gry = games.id
where (games.status = 2 and games.winner_user_id <> 49 and games.owner_user_id = 49)
   or games.join_user_id = 49;
```

where you want it to be

```
select *
from games
inner join prowizja on prowizja.id_gry = games.id
where (games.status = 2 and games.winner_user_id <> 49)
  and (games.owner_user_id = 49 or games.join_user_id = 49);
```

Conclusion: Use parentheses whenever mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Minor syntax hiccup in there my friend

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using or clause in your query. Update your query as per your requirement. If your just want to don't show record of winner id 49. You can use below query.

```
select *
from `games`
    inner join `prowizja` on `prowizja`.`id_gry` = `games`.`id`
where `games`.`status` = 2 and `games`.`winner_user_id` != 49
 and (`games`.`owner_user_id` = 49 or `games`.`join_user_id` = 49)
```